# Can we change Web Address and Moodle directory of moodle platform?

Tags: php, moodle

Moodle installation Web Address and Moodle directory are set differently in localhost and server.

> I tried to change the default location of moodle directory from server by manually.

I cannot change it, should i upgrade Moodle platform to newest version?

Thanks

Comment: Edit config.php in the web root folder to set the server and the data directory.

Comment: yes I did, and it changes sucessfully in localhost. Bt in server i cant do this

Comment: So there is an issue with access to the server rather than Moodle? You don't have permissions to edit config.php on the server?

Comment: yes sir.Unlike local i can't edit config file on the server.

Comment: If you can't edit config.php then you won't be able to change the default settings.

Comment: can't i change the config.php file ?? is there any solution of it? plz reply

Answer (score 0):

The web address and data directory can be changed in `config.php`

But it looks like you don't have permission to edit that file.

I would suggest using a different host.

Comment: Its my client's host. I can't do change.